# OBS Studio Virtual Camera and Iriun seem to be in Conflict

Tags: v4l2loopback, obs-studio

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop.  I have installed OBS Studio and Iriun.  Both work fine as long as I don't try to use the Virtual Camera from OBS.  When I do, the Iriun screen turns a pixalated green color and flickers to my iphone then back to the pixalated screen again. If I turn off Virtual Camera all is fine.  It seems there are two apps trying to use the same V4l2loopback device and this may be causing a conflict.
I would like to solve this problem so I can use Iriun and OBS with Zoom and Teams.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Locate the OBS installation folder (***which obs-studio***) and run ***chmod 111 [folder name].***
This would give OBS more privileges (read, write, execute).
There are many possibilities to what could be causing the issue, but sometimes it is just about OBS not having the execution privileges to some applications/devices.

Comment: I will definitely give that a try, but I think you mean chmod 777 not chmod 111 which will give no privileges to user, group and others..  Thank you.

Comment: Tried changing permissions an still the same issue.  Thanks for the ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Answer ripped from [OBS forums](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/new-virtual-cam-choose-device.137869/), copied here for posterity.

Adding information as I had the same problem. Iriun Webcam and OBS both seem to use the first available `/dev/video{N}` device. To fix this, you need to edit the modprobe files for Iriun. See below.

Hi Simon.

I've installed Iriun Webcam today in my Ubuntu and I've had the same problem here.

Good news: I've managed to fix it using 2 devices for v4l2loopback. Here is how I did:

1. Edit (using sudo) the file /etc/modprobe.d/iriunwebcam-options.conf

```
options v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1 devices=2 video_nr=8,9 card_label="OBS Virtualcam,Iriun Webcam"
options snd-aloop index=1
```

Note: Don't change the number at snd-aloop line: it is specific to your system (in my case it is 1). Watch for video_nr numbers. Be sure you are not using one already in use (check it --- no need for sudo --- in terminal: v4l2-ctl --list-devices)

2. Edit (using sudo) the file /etc/modules-load.d/iriunwebcam.conf

```
v4l2loopback
options v4l2loopback video_nr=8,9
options v4l2loopback card_label="OBS Virtualcam,Iriun Webcam"
snd-aloop
```

Note: Use the same parameters as in the previous file for video_nr and card_label (not sure if it is mandatory, I've not checked this). This file ensures that Ubuntu will load these two virtual video devices at startup.

3. I'm not sure if the next (and final) step is needed or just a system reboot is good enough. But before rebooting Ubuntu, I did in terminal:
   sudo update-initramfs -u

After reboot, both Iriun Webcam and OBS Virtualcam are visible in the system and do not interfere with each other (I've used the Iriun Webcam as a source in OBS Studio and the OBS Virtualcam as video device for MS Teams and G Meet).

The references for this solution started at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62075776/running-two-v4l2loopback-devices-with-their-individual-properties)

Hope it works for you!